# How to place image in tkinter textbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, cryptography

So I'm making a program that decrypts encrypted data in files and you can view it only from the program. I am using custom tkinter for the GUI and I've stumbled on something I'm not quite sure how to do. I want the program to be able to show images also but I have no idea how to put an image in the tkinter textbox. This is the data window file:

```
import sys
import platform
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from customtkinter import *
from CTkListbox import *

global PLATFORM
PLATFORM = platform.system()

with open('bin/main_path.txt', 'r') as file:
    get_path = file.read()

get_path_len = len(get_path)
get_path = get_path[:get_path_len - 7]

sys.path.append(get_path)

# This removes the data widgets when the back button is pressed
def delete_data_widgets():
    from main_menu_module import main_menu
    from main_menu_module import key_path
    from main_menu_module import fernet

    # Delete the widgets from the data menu
    data_frame_left.destroy()
    data_frame_right.destroy()
    main_menu(key_path, fernet)

# This is the command for the listbox in the data menu
def data_listbox_show(selected_option):
    data_textbox.configure(state='normal')
    data_textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')

    index_num = names.index(selected_option)

    data_textbox.insert('end', data_info[index_num])

    print(names[index_num])
    print(names[index_num].split('.', 1)[1])
    
    data_textbox.configure(state='disabled')

# This is the data menu
def data_menu():
    from main_menu_module import fernet
    from main import root

    data = os.listdir('data')
    data_len = len(data)

    global names
    names = []
    global data_info
    data_info = []

    for file in data:
        # Setting up the path to the file
        if PLATFORM == 'Windows':
            file_path = 'data\\' + str(file)
        else:
            file_path = 'data/' + str(file)

        # Opening the file
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fileR: original = fileR.read()

        # Decrypting the file
        decrypted = fernet.decrypt(original)

        # Filling in the info from the profiles
        data_info.append(decrypted)

        # Decrypting the names
        old_name = bytes(str(file), 'utf-8')
        new_name = str(fernet.decrypt(old_name))
        new_name = new_name[2:]
        new_name = new_name[:-1]

        # Filling in the names of the profiles
        names.append(new_name)

    global data_frame_left
    data_frame_left = CTkFrame(master=root, width=100, height=100)

    global data_back_button
    data_back_button = CTkButton(master=data_frame_left, text='Back', command=delete_data_widgets)
    data_back_button.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

    global data_listbox
    data_listbox = CTkListbox(master=data_frame_left, command=data_listbox_show, scrollbar_button_color='#1f6aa5', border_color='#1f6aa5')
    data_listbox.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    i = 1
    for name in names:
        data_listbox.insert(i, name)
        i = i + 1

    data_frame_left.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

    global data_frame_right
    data_frame_right = CTkFrame(master=root)

    global data_textbox
    data_textbox = CTkTextbox(master=data_frame_right, scrollbar_button_color='#1f6aa5', border_color='#1f6aa5')
    data_textbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    data_textbox.configure(state='disabled')

    data_frame_right.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're talking about tkinter textbox  or  customtkinter CTkTextbox?

Comment: I am using CTkTextbox, but it's basically the same

Answer (score 1):

`customtkinter.CTkTextbox` will raise exception when its `.image_create()` function is executed:

```py
class CTkTextbox(CTkBaseClass):
    ...

    def image_create(self, index, **kwargs):
        raise AttributeError("embedding images is forbidden, because would be incompatible with scaling")

    ...
```

However, you can call `.image_create()` on its internal `tkinter.Text` widget *if you don't mind the above warning*:

```py
from PIL import ImageTk
...

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="/path/to/image/file")
data_textbox._textbox.image_create("end", image=image)
...
```

---

**Updated**: how to show the decrypted images:

```py
from PIL import ImageTk
...

def data_listbox_show(selected_option):
    data_textbox.configure(state='normal')
    data_textbox.delete('1.0', 'end')

    index_num = names.index(selected_option)

    #data_textbox.insert('end', data_info[index_num])
    ### assume that all the data are images
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=data_info[index_num])
    data_textbox._textbox.image_create("end", image=image)
    # save the reference of the image to avoid garbage collection
    data_textbox.image = image

    print(names[index_num])
    print(names[index_num].split('.', 1)[1])

    data_textbox.configure(state='disabled')

...
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because all the files in the data folder are encrypted, even the names. And pillow doesn't allow me to use an encrypted file as an image.

Comment: @dkolev00 You just state in your question that you don't know how to show image in a text box. So my answer addresses this.  If it is not the case, you should state the issue clearly. Your code can decrypt the file, so you can use the decrypted file.